# pip install on virtualenv

Tags: python, import, pip

I installed VMWare on window and using a virtualenv for python project.

I activated the project `project1` and pip3 install  xxxxx modules I need.

But some of them had an import error and when I deactivated the virtualenv and pip3 install xxxx on the root, the import error is resolved.

Are we supposed to pip install on the root, even though we activate the virtualenv? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
# A virtualenv's python pip call:
$ project1/bin/python -m pip install xxxxx
```

Where:

- project1: Is the env folder inside your root folder that contain all
  your python modules included python it self.
- -m  is a python flag stand for:  "run library module as a script" .
- pip: Is the package manager.
- install: is the pip command to install the desired module.
- xxxxx: its the desired python module (no, its not about film genres)

P.S: In this way you ensure to be using the python version you installed on your virtualenv **unequivocally**